# Can I ask the system to reload my app permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions, aidl

Is there any way to programmaticaly ask the Android to reload/regrant my app permissions without reinstalling the app or rebooting the device on a non-rooted device?

## Why do I need it?

My app (ClientApp) is binding to a service declared in AIDL by another app (ServiceApp). ServiceApp is a third-party app which I can't modify and it declares a permission that ClientApp needs to bind to its service, so I added that permission to my ClientApp's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.service.API" />
```

When I install ServiceApp before installing ClientApp everything works fine. However, when I first install ClientApp and then install ServiceApp I get an exception when calling bindService on ServiceApp's service in ClientApp:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.example.service.API pkg=com.example.service }
```

My understanding is that my app is not granted the requested permission on installation because it's not declared in the system before ServiceApp is installed. I can fix it on Android < 5.0 by declaring ServiceApp's permission in ClientApp's manifest but it's not possible in Android 5.0+ because of security reasons.

If I could somehow reload the permissions (which apparently happens on device reboot) from my code I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permission is granted. If it is granted, you can use it, otherwise you can show permission request as popup

Camera permission example:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    // permission granted
}
else
{
    // ask permission to user
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, Constants.PermissionRequestCodes.CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, onRequestPermissionsResult gets -1 (PERMISSION_DENIED) for this permission. It is granted only after device reboot.